When do people use「お祖父さん」vs.「おじいさん」?
Of course the two are read exactly the same, but in a scenario where you would be reading/writing the word (books, texting, etc.), when would you use the Kanji version of the word おじいさん? Is there any actual difference between the two (functionally or contextually)?

We also have お[爺]{じい}さん・お[婆]{ばあ}さん. Do you know what [祖父]{そふ}・[祖母]{そぼ} mean?

Related, perhaps? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/4641/9831

@chocolate I see what you're saying. So if the word is written out, in order to differentiate between "grandfather" and "elderly man", you would have to write the kanji forms of those words (お祖父さん/お爺さん)?

I think that means you could differentiate with the kanjis too, but that's something you can usually infer from the context too. So if you know the right kanji and if they're adequate to the target who's gonna read your message, you write it with the kanjis, but if not, there's no problem using hiragana.

Sometimes it's entirely optional. If the person referred has grandchildren, and the reader knows that, then it makes sense to write お祖父さん, but it's also fine to write おじいさん. (This applies to many other cases where you have kanji and hiragana choices - just because there is a kanji version doesn't mean you have to write that way.)
Sometimes the author tries to implicitly introduce that the person is a grandfather succinctly by using the kanji, like in the very first line of a novel. In that case, the other choice would force the author to supply the information (that the person is a grandfather) some other way, because おじいさん by itself could mean an elderly man.
